# How to set array in input?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I want to pass an array of json objects to the controller using a form, for example:

*HTML code:*

```
<input type="hidden" name="arr" id="arr"/>
```

*JS code:*

```
Var arr=[{'Id':1,'name':'aaa'}];
 document.getElementById("arr").value=arr;
```

How can I set the value of the array on the input?

Comment: what do you want to do? Do you want to submit the array value to the controller? which framework you are using?

Comment: You firstly need proper quotes and correct syntax, I assume you wrote this on iOS since `var` also needs to be lowercase

Comment: First your html is not valid and why input type hidden ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/81h7jgf2/) :

Html code:

```
<input type="text" name="arr" id="arr" />
```

JS Code:

```
 var arr = [{"Id":1,"name":"aaa"}];
 document.getElementById("arr").value = JSON.stringify(arr);
 console.log(document.getElementById("arr").value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="arr" id="arr" />

var arr=[{"name":"ABC"}];
console.log( document.getElementById("arr"));
document.getElementById("arr").value=arr[0].name;
```

Comment: Sorry, i want json array , no array